# Can't connect to App Store on iPhone 6s when on Wi-Fi

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, dns

I don't understand why this is happening now. This was never a problem.

I have tried the following without success:

1. Reset network settings.
2. Make sure the date/time are correct — they are.
3. Reset my internet modem.
4. Sign out of Apple ID for iTunes, then sign back in.

What worked was turning off my Wi-Fi.

Here's my problem with that though: why would Apple make you turn off your Wi-Fi for you to update your apps and software, or even to sign in using an Apple ID? Why do I need to use my Mobile data to update my phone?

Apparently it's because of my DNS. When adding DNS 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, everything started to work. I replaced some IP address with the 8.8.4.4.

Why was this happening? Why was there a different IP address in there? Why now? never had this happen to me in a decade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with Apple and Apple do not have any problem with you using Wi-Fi for connecting to the App Store. Your DNS was likely provided by your ISP, which seems to have been having trouble routing the Apple domains. By changing the DNS to Google's DNS which can perform the routing correctly, the problem is resolved. I suggest you contact whoever provided your previous DNS.